# How can i get my PrimeNumber generator to work?

Tags: java, return, generator

I tried to write an primenumber generator. The method calcall() should return prime numbers (2,3,5,7...). Unfortunately I get the error, that the method doesn't returns an integer, wich I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
package primenumber;

public class primecalc {

    public static int calcall(int a) {            //actual generator
        int konstante = a;                        //is this number a prime num?     
        int divisor = a-1;                        //divisor
        int var1 = 0;                             //variable = 0
        while(divisor>1) {                        
            int quotient = konstante%divisor;     //calc modulo
            if(quotient == 0) {                   //if modulo==0 switch var1 to 
                var1++;                           //1 -> no primenumber                           
                break;                            //stop calculating
            } else {                              //else keep calculculating
                divisor--;                        //until divisor <= 1 
            }
        }
        if(var1==0) {                             //if var1 still 0; 
            return konstante;                     //is a primnumber -> 
        }                                         //return konstante                            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {      //main function
        int number = 3;                           //start with 3
        while(True) {                             //(i'll add 2 manually)
            System.out.println(calcall(number));  //print the prime number
            number++;                             //increase number by one
        }               
    }    
}
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type int    
    at primenumber/primenumber.primecalc.calcall(primecalc.java:5)
    at primenumber/primenumber.primecalc.main(primecalc.java:28)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Multiline comments start at `/*` and end at `*/`. Everything in between is ignored by the compiler. Check your code.

Comment: This is a legit question from a legit newbie and should not have been put on hold. It's not a typographical error: it's a cognition problem that new programmers often bump into.

Answer (score 2):

The gray lines on the code you posted are being ignored by the compiler.

The use of `/*` and `*/` makes everything between these seen by the compiler as comments. And that is why those lines are grayed out. If you want to comment on the same line as the code, I'd advise you to use `//`.

Also, it is common practise to use multi-line comments only to describe functions and place them just above the header of the function. Any other comments should be short, concise and describe functionality. Good variable names and well written code should do most of the explaining, and single line comments should be used when it's a bit harder toperceive what's going on.

Cheers

Comment: That was not my question.

Comment: @Laurids actually, it answers your question. You get the error, because the return statement is regarded as a comment.

Comment: How so?

The problem is at line 28, which I'm guessing is "return konstante". Since that line is commented out, the compiler doesn't see it and thus the function actually has no expression returning the expected value (int).

Comment: Ah okay sorry. In the actual code there are no comments. I just added them here for better understanding.

Comment: I rewrote the programm and the problem is solved now. THanks.

Comment: @Laurids glad I could help. If you deem fit, mark this answer as correct so others who stumble across the same issue can see it.